# Is there a way to expand the mount column of discus?

Tags: disk-usage

discus output:

```
    ~$ discus
    Mount           Total         Used         Avail      Prcnt      Graph
    /run            788.7 MB       1.9 MB     786.8 MB     0.2%   [----------]
    /               46.49 GB     20.57 GB     25.93 GB    44.2%   [****------]
    +l/security         0 KB         0 KB         0 KB     0.0%   [----------]
    /dev/shm         3.85 GB     300.4 MB      3.56 GB     7.6%   [*---------]
    /run/lock         5.0 MB         4 KB       5.0 MB     0.1%   [----------]
    +/fs/cgroup      3.85 GB         0 KB      3.85 GB     0.0%   [----------]
    +up/unified         0 KB         0 KB         0 KB     0.0%   [----------]
    +up/systemd         0 KB         0 KB         0 KB     0.0%   [----------]
⋮
    +rnel/debug         0 KB         0 KB         0 KB     0.0%   [----------]
    +dev/mqueue         0 KB         0 KB         0 KB     0.0%   [----------]
    +/hugepages         0 KB         0 KB         0 KB     0.0%   [----------]
    +rpc_pipefs         0 KB         0 KB         0 KB     0.0%   [----------]
    +nel/config         0 KB         0 KB         0 KB     0.0%   [----------]
    +onnections         0 KB         0 KB         0 KB     0.0%   [----------]
    +26-1604/98     140.8 MB     140.8 MB         0 KB   100.0%   [**********]
    +26-1604/97     140.8 MB     140.8 MB         0 KB   100.0%   [**********]
    +acters/367      14.8 MB      14.8 MB         0 KB   100.0%   [**********]
    +hemes/1313      42.9 MB      42.9 MB         0 KB   100.0%   [**********]
    +/core/8039      89.1 MB      89.1 MB         0 KB   100.0%   [**********]
    +hemes/1353      44.2 MB      44.2 MB         0 KB   100.0%   [**********]
    +ore18/1265      54.6 MB      54.6 MB         0 KB   100.0%   [**********]
    +ulator/544       4.2 MB       4.2 MB         0 KB   100.0%   [**********]
    +acters/359      14.8 MB      14.8 MB         0 KB   100.0%   [**********]
    +ulator/536       4.2 MB       4.2 MB         0 KB   100.0%   [**********]
    +/core/8213      89.1 MB      89.1 MB         0 KB   100.0%   [**********]
    +me-logs/81       1.0 MB       1.0 MB         0 KB   100.0%   
⋮
    /tmp             3.85 GB      16.0 MB      3.84 GB     0.4%   [----------]
    /library       244.14 GB    206.76 GB     37.38 GB    84.7%   [********--]
```

I would like to figure out what the mount points are in discus.  Is there any way to do this?  Additionally, if the items are at 100% are all related somehow, is there a way to suppress them?  It appears that if I knew what they were, I could simply modify my ~/.discusrc file:

```
##  Filesystems to ignore.
opts["skip_list" = ["/dev/pts", "/proc", "/dev". "/proc/usb", "/sys"]
```

but I'm left with insufficient information to adjust that line.  I don't see anything helpful in https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/discus.1.html

Comment: What about expanding the size of the terminal window?

Comment: Lie to `discus` about terminal width thusly: `COLUMNS=500 discus`.